# Make a threadline using vuetify?

Tags: css, flexbox, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make an avatar threadline that extends from avatar to avatar using Vuetify. [I've made a working example of what I'm trying to accomplishing here](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/vYGOGpV) using just vanilla CSS and flexbox. What I'm trying to do is port my vanilla example into vuetify:

[image]

**Vuetify Card**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto mt-10"
      width="344"
      outlined
    >
      <v-list class="d-flex">
        
        <v-list-item-avatar class="align-self-start">
          <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/32" alt="John">
          <div class="threadline"></div>
        </v-list-item-avatar>

        <v-list-item-content >
          <div class="questrial font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 14px">Daniel Frazier <span class="font-weight-medium grey--text">17 hrs ago</span></div>
          
          <p>
            Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
          </p>
        </v-list-item-content>
        
      </v-list>

       <div class="comment-buttons">
        <span>Reply to thread</span>
        <span>View/add details</span>
      </div>
      
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Specific Vuetify Code From Above**

```
<v-list-item-avatar class="align-self-start">
   <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/32" alt="John">
   <div class="threadline"></div>
</v-list-item-avatar>
```

**CSS**

```
.threadline{
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}
```

**Threadline using vanilla CSS and flexbox**

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img class="circle" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/32">
    <div class="threadline"></div>
</div>

.avatar {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.threadline{
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}
```

[In my Vuetify codepen](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/zYqxdvO?editors=1100) the threadline is aligning beside the avatar. I want to make it align like in the picture and my vanilla css.

Comment: try using vuetify timeline component to get it done https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/timelines/

Comment: @chans, The problem is that the line extends past the avatar at the top and also I don't intend to have a second line if there isn't a response. Is it possible to not have that?